# Why is mean not 0 and std not 1 after data standardisation [(X - Mean)/Std]?

Tags: standardization

I've recently tried to standardize my dataset (X) with the following formula Y = (X - Mean)/Std.

Let's say the result of the dataset after the standardization is Y.

I expect my dataset Y to have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1, but instead, I get a mean value of -5.691002433701753e-16 and an std value of 0.9999999999999997

The difference is very little but is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: What software are you using? I've gotten R to give me exactly 0 and 1 (doesn't mean R can't fail at that), but I could believe that, say, Excel doesn't have quite that same precision.

Comment: I'm manipulating my dataset using python with the NumPy library

Comment: If the new mean and standard deviation is closer to $0$ and $1,$ respectively, than you have significant figures in your dataset, then you practically have correct standardization.

Comment: Because the numbers represent a machine precision result. If you want a more precise result,  you need to do the calculations in extended precision. In specific,  python has an extended precision package; http://mpmath.org/.

Comment: Very basic explanation of why floating point arithmetic isn't exact starts here: https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/  .... a much more complete but less basic discussion: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html .... you shouldn't be using computers to do important calculations unless you have at least a basic understanding of how they work; once you do, many things become clear that would otherwise be obscure (and you gain some sense of when and how they can go very wrong; in some statistical calculations, it can matter more often than you might expect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double precision floats have about 15 decimal digits of precision, so this is the expected behavior. For more information, familiarize yourself with [IEEE 754.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

Comment: thank you for the reference, I will look into it